# OSX deployment: 3rd party library loads plugins (custom) in /Applications rather than bundle

Tags: macos, qt, plugins

I'm trying to create an application bundle for Mac OSX. I'm using a 3rd party library (Marble, part of KDE, but build for Qt-only) that uses its own custom plugins, and I'm not sure how to deal with that. Here's what I've done:

1. Compile my bundle
2. Use macdeployqt to copy Qt libraries to the bundle and tell the binary to use these libraries libraries (this appears to copy the Marble library libmarblewidget.dylib to the application bundle, and to fix its library dependencies as well)
3. Copy the Marble plugins to bundle.app/Contents/PlugIns/marble (where bundle.app is my bundle), and use install_name_tool to link them to the Qt and Marble libraries in the bundle.

However, my application won't run. I've run it with DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES=1 to see what's getting loaded, and it all looks good until a plugin from /Applications/Marble.app/Contents/MacOS/resources/plugins/ is loaded rather than from the PlugIns directory in my bundle. At this point, the plugin tries to load the /Developer Qt libraries rather than the bundle copies (as well as the copy of libmarblewidget.dylib I've got in /usr/local/lib) and it all falls apart.

It's possible that I've misunderstood the problem, but it seems to me that the issue is that the 3rd party library (libmarblewidget.dylib) loads the Marble application bundle plugins, which then mess everything up. Assuming I'm correct, is there any way to tell this library to use the PlugIns directory inside my application bundle? Do I need to recompile it?

Comment: If your run otool -L on the plugin dylib, does it have paths to the plugins, which you can set with install_name_tool?

Comment: You mean the library dylib? Either way, I've run otool -L on the plugins (.so files) and the library, and everything that shows up is either in the bundle (@executable_path/../something) or a system (not Qt) library.

Comment: You've mentioned plugins (.so files). If they are shared library .so files as used by linux, that is going to be a problem as OSX doesn't use that format, but has its own binary type called Mach-O. This contains headers for the dynamic linker dyld to fix up dynamic library calls. See here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/MachORuntime/Reference/reference.html

Comment: I know, but that's how the Marble library compiles its plugins (even on Mac OSX). They actually load just fine with the Marble application, as well as in my application, as long as I don't fix my bundle to use the bundle libraries. This is because the location of plugins is basically hard-coded into the library. I'll post a full solution once I've sorted out some details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marble hard-codes the plugin (and data) locations in the file MarbleDirs.cpp. The expected location for plugins is

```
bundle.app/Contents/Resources/plugins
```

and for data:

```
bundle.app/Contents/Resources/data
```

As long as plugins and data are in these directories, and IDs and links for all plugins are fixed using install_name_tool, the application will run fine, linking only to Qt and Marble libraries within the bundle. The fact that plugins are .so files rather than .dylib doesn't seem to be a problem.

It doesn't matter what the value of plugins is set to in qt.conf, libmarblewidget.dylib will always look in these locations.